# Repeated First Data In JavaScript Console Log Output By Chrome Inspect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, devtools, inspect

Currently learning javascript, and I am curious on the console data output in Chrome inspect. Whenever I ran the HTML file for the first time, the console always output the first data two times. What could be the cause of it? Is there any significance to such when the JS script is running?

[image: Chrome inspect console output]

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Select Exercise</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <hr/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <select class="form-control" id="select_demo" onchange=onKidChange(this)></select>
                            <br/>
                            <h3 id="agevalue"></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var jsonDataObject = [
            {"model": "A", "identifier": 1, "fields": {"name": "Stan", "age": "12"}},
            {"model": "B", "identifier": 2, "fields": {"name": "Brett", "age": "14"}}
        ]
        
        var kidModels = document.getElementById("select_demo")
        
        var kidAge = document.getElementById("agevalue")
        
        var kidTry
                
        function setup(){           
            for(var a = 0; a < jsonDataObject.length; a++){
                var option = document.createElement("option")
                option.innerHTML = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].name
                option.value = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age
                kidModels.options.add(option)
                kidAge.innerHTML = kidModels.value
                kidTry = kidModels.value
                console.log(kidTry)
            }
        }
        
        function onKidChange(selected){
            for(var a=0; a < jsonDataObject.length; a++){
                if(selected.value == jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age){
                    kidAge.innerHTML = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age
                    kidTry = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age
                    console.log(kidTry)
                }
            }
        }
        
        window.onload = setup
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In for loop of setup, default selected value for dropdown is the first element of array. And you are always printing this value to console.

```js
   var jsonDataObject = [
            {"model": "A", "identifier": 1, "fields": {"name": "Stan", "age": "12"}},
            {"model": "B", "identifier": 2, "fields": {"name": "Brett", "age": "14"}}
        ]
        
        var kidModels = document.getElementById("select_demo")
        
        var kidAge = document.getElementById("agevalue")
        
        var kidTry
                
        function setup(){           
            for(var a = 0; a < jsonDataObject.length; a++){
                var option = document.createElement("option")
                option.innerHTML = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].name
                option.value = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age
                kidModels.options.add(option)
                kidAge.innerHTML = kidModels.value
                kidTry = kidModels.value
                console.log(kidTry,'----')
            }
        }
        
        function onKidChange(selected){
            for(var a=0; a < jsonDataObject.length; a++){
                if(selected.value == jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age){
                    kidAge.innerHTML = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age
                    kidTry = jsonDataObject[a]["fields"].age
                    console.log(kidTry,'++++')
                }
            }
        }
        
        window.onload = setup
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Select Exercise</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <hr/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <select class="form-control" id="select_demo" onchange=onKidChange(this)></select>
                            <br/>
                            <h3 id="agevalue"></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```